# Error showing in eclipse project explorer, but empty problems description

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Java Maven project imported into Eclipse. The Project Explorer is showing an error (red x) on my Java Resources node and the project node, but not in any source files nodes.

The Problems view shows one error, but when I expand the error it contains no description.

I have even walked though the project properties dialog looking for an error indication but don't see anything.

I have tried a Maven project update and forced update of project dependencies. I have restarted eclipse. I have deleted the local copy of the project and pulled it down fresh. In all cases I still get this mystery error.

The project is imported using m2e with the m2e-subversive connecter. A standalone Maven build succeeds.

Any suggestions on how to drill down this error? In all my years using Eclipse I've never seen an empty error description.

Comment: it might be because eclipse is not identifying it as maven project..just right click on project-> configure -> convert to maven project  try it out..

Comment: unfortunately it is identified. I can even force a maven project update. My guess is that it is an error in a plugin that isn't reporting it's cause, in which case I may be out of luck.